Flexes and the Hessian matrix
Let $E/K$ be the elliptic curve defined by
$$ F(X,Y,Z)=Y^2Z-X^3-AXZ^2-BZ^3$$
After a few pages of calculation one sees that for a point $P\in E$ we have $[3]P=O$ if and only if
$$\det H=8(3Y^2X+3AX^2Z+9BXZ^2-A^2Z^3)$$
where $H$ is the Hessian matrix evaluates to zero at $P$. Therefore $E[3]$ which is the 3-torsion subgroup of $E$ is exactly the points on the intersection of $E$ and the degree three curve defined by $\det H$. Now, Silverman AEC exercise III.3.9(c) asks us to prove that $E[3]$ consists of exactly nine points. According to Bezout's theorem the intersection of the curve defined by the determinant of the Hessian and $E$ must intersect nine times counting with multiplicity. I have seen exercise 5.23 in Fulton's book, but want to see if there is an elementary method (i.e. a method that does not use the definition of multiplicity) to prove that these nine points are distinct.

Since $F$ and $\det H$ are coprime and both vanish at $[0:1:0]$, if we show that there are eight common roots of these polynomials where $Z\neq 0$, then we'll win: this will give us exactly the nine distinct intersection points we crave.
Start by dehomogenizing our polynomials with respect to $Z$ and dropping constant factors to get $$f=y^2-x^3-Ax-B, \qquad h= 3xy^2 + 3Ax^2 +9Bx-A^2.$$ Computing the resultant of these polynomials with respect to $y$, we get $(-A^2 + 12Bx + 6Ax^2 + 3x^4)^2$, which vanishes at $x$ iff there is some $y$ so that $(x,y)$ is on both curves. Since $f$ and $h$ are both invariant under $y\mapsto -y$, if we can show this polynomial has 4 distinct roots in $x$, we'll win, since each such $x$ will correspond to two $y$ so that $(x,y)$ is in $V(f,h)$.
To check this, we take the discriminant of $-A^2 + 12Bx + 6Ax^2 + 3x^4$ with respect to $x$ to get $-6912(16A^6 + 216A^3B^2 + 729B^4)=-6912(4A^3+27B^2)^2$, which vanishes iff $4A^3+27B^2=0$. But that's zero iff $x^3+Ax+B$ has a multiple root, which cannot occur if $F$ defines an elliptic curve. So indeed $V(f,h)$ consists of eight points and $V(F,H)$ consists of nine points.

Thank you for your response. When I compute the resultant I get $(-3x^4-6Ax^2-12Bx+A^2)^2$. Are we using different definitions of the resultant? Also if we assume that we are working in characteristic $\neq 2,3$ can't we just argue that the derivative of $-3x^4-6Ax^2-12Bx+A^2$ doesn't vanish since $12\neq 0$?

Aha! There is an $8$ in $h$ which you dropped when defining $h$ but then assumed in calculating the resultant.

@Navid yep, good spot. I don't agree that we can argue with the derivative - we need to find four distinct roots of that polynomial, and non-vanishing of the derivative does not imply that. I guess we're also making an assumption here about not working in characteristic 2 or 3, since the Hessian determinant vanishes identically there, and not every elliptic curve can be put in a short Weierstrass equation in those characteristics. But there are ways around that.

Yes, we have to show that the resultant and the derivative of the resultant don't have a common root. Thanks.
